# nullReferenceException on nested models

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need help understand why I getting a null object reference here:

I have 2 models:

```
public class loadViewModel
{
    public importacaoConfig importacaoConfig { get; set; }
}

public class importacaoConfig
{
    public List<DocTypeModel> tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Im my controler I am passing a List to the model:

```
gedaiapp.Models.loadViewModel model = new gedaiapp.Models.loadViewModel();    
model.importacaoConfig.tipo = obj; -> Here obj is of type List<DocTypeModel>
```

This gives me:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have checked and the obj list has 3 elements.
Which reference is null here? I don´t get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

`model.importacaoConfig.tipo`

You **haven't instantiated** `importacaoConfig`, so it's null (hence why you get the exception on that line.

Add this line to instantiate it (between your two existing lines):

```
model.importacaoConfig = new importacaoConfig();
```

So your controller would be:

```
gedaiapp.Models.loadViewModel model = new gedaiapp.Models.loadViewModel();
model.importacaoConfig = new importacaoConfig();    
model.importacaoConfig.tipo = obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really check in the debugger but I would assume that the following is null:

```
model.importacaoConfig
```

as you have not initialised it in when you create your `loadViewModel`.

You need to have a constructor that does the following:

```
public loadViewModel()
{
    importacaoConfig = new importacaoConfig();
}
```

I'd also think about giving your variables different names to the classes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
importacaoConfig.tipo=new List<DocTypeModel>();
```

You have not initialized `tipo`